# Removing unneeded (?) folder after installation

Tags: jdk

I've installed the Java Development Kit, following this guide:

[How to install JDK on Fedora](https://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/#)

I've installed the JDK with the following commands:

```
cd /opt/jdk1.8.0_121/
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java 2
alternatives --config java
```

I've completed successfully the installation. But I don't know if the initial folder `/opt/jdk1.8.0_121` is still needed for the JDK in order to properly work, or if I can delete it.

Answer (score 9):

You need to keep `/opt/jdk1.8.0_121`, that’s where the JDK is installed. The `alternatives` commands didn’t copy the installation anywhere else, they just set various links up so that the default Java installation used on the system is the installation contained in `/opt/jdk1.8.0_121`.

Note that you can also install JDK 8 (as provided by the OpenJDK) by installing the `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` Fedora package instead:

```
dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Answer (score -3):

After you list your folder you can rm your folder. You can protect yourself from deleting unwanted folders by checking which jdk you are using: `javac -v` and `which javac` are good starting points. Pipe your folder's name to rm like this: `echo "jdkfolder | rm`.

Comment: This looks wrong on several accounts; in particular, `rm` doesn't process its standard input.